# Preparation stage and initialization stage of java class loader

Tags: java, classloader

I am not able to understand the difference between following lines  ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2 )

A) Preparation involves initializing static fields to the default values.

B) Initialization of a class consists of executing initializers for static fields (class variables) declared in the class.

Does it mean that 'a' will get assign the default value in "preparation" stage and 'b' will get assign the value in "Initialization" stage:

```
static int a;  
static int b=2;
```

Comment: Modified the question to make it more clear

Comment: See my updated answer to your modified question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Initializing to default values" means that the fields are set to the following values:

- boolean: false
- int, long, byte, short: 0
- double, float: +0.0
- char: '\u0000'
- reference types: null

"Initializing by executing initializers" means that now the expressions that are assigned to those static fields are evaluated and assigned to them.

So, in the "preparation" stage, your `a` and `b` will be created and will receive the value `0`. In the "initialization" stage, `b` will receive the value `2`.

---

This is easy to verify using a method that has a side-effect. Instead of assigning simple "2" to `b`, we are calling a static method that returns the value `2`, but it also prints information about the variables before doing so:

```
public class SimpleTest {

    private static int a;
    private static int b = printAAndBReturning2("initializer");

    static {
        printAAndBReturning2("static initializing block");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        printAAndBReturning2("main");

    }

    public static int printAAndBReturning2(String where) {
        System.out.printf("In %s a is %d and b is %d%n", where, SimpleTest.a, SimpleTest.b);
        return 2;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
In initializer a is 0 and b is 0
In static initializing block a is 0 and b is 2
In main a is 0 and b is 2
```

This demonstration also serves to warn you about using methods that are ran during the initialization stage.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Please don't take it in the wrong sense- Do you know any way using which I can verify your answer " In the "preparation" stage, your a and b will be created and will receive the value 0. In the "initialization" stage, b will receive the value 2".

Comment: Did you ever verify it or are you interpreting the statement?

Comment: @nantitv Then will you consider marking my answer as accepted? It's the StackOverflow equivalent of "thank you", and perhaps you should do the same for previous answers to your SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

All fields of primitive types will be auto-initialized to default values.
For int is 0. So `a == 0`. You can check default values [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).
It have the difference on non-primitive types (classes).
So
`Font a;` -> `a == null` (If you will try to use methods of `a` you will get `a is not initialized`.
`Font b = new Font("Dialog", 16, Font.BOLD);` -> `b == ...` (I think you understand).